# How to use Wordnet in SQL

Tags: sql, nlp

How to use Wordnet in SQL database. Does it exists anywhere can someone give me step by step procedure

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, actually, you can use the WordNet SQL Builder (http://wnsqlbuilder.sourceforge.net/).  Instructions for performing the conversion are straightforward: http://wnsqlbuilder.sourceforge.net/howto.html.  Basically you download the code, decompress it, and run the script.

Comment: Is there a port for SQL Server?